# Tidying Google Shopping data XML file

Tags: xml, product, feed

A client of mine is having problems with their XML shopping file.

Rather than having all of the products namespaces on one row, each namespace has its own row.

Example:

```
ns1:title       ns1:title2    ns1:link      ns1:description etc etc etc 
website.co.uk   product name
website.co.uk                 product link
website.co.uk                               product description
```

Now, I am very new when it comes to XML files, and I apologies, but I get the general idea.

Each product has 16 different namespaces / fields, so each product has 16 rows of data giving 54941 rows of data, where there should only be 1/16 of that.

How do I put all of the data for each product on one row?

Answer (score 0):

The example code you posted looks more like a txt file then a XMl file.

google allows you to submit both formats. Which format are you trying to create?

You can read more about the file formats [here](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160567?hl=en&ref_topic=3404777)